# Div width inconsistancy - Cross browser issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have done most of my coding for www.chronasleep.com using google chrome (big mistake) & when I checked on Firefox it was all screwed up. I can't seem to pinpoint why it is acting like this on Firefox. Any suggestions?

Here is the site on [Chrome](http://chronasleep.com/img/Chrome.png)
and one of the problems on [Firefox](http://chronasleep.com/img/Firefox.png)

These images above are currently the biggest issue. This is the Press section on the page. The divs on Firefox are not holding their width and are instead not allowing the text to wrap. Could that be the problem? How can I make the text wrap?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: man i don't think anyone can solve with ease..you have to hire developer or freelancer for this..sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing

```
.row-center {
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
}
```

And adding:

```
.row-center {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Seems to fix it. Just make sure it doesn't change something you don't want to change or write more specific and targeting CSS.

Comment: it will solve the footer issue but if you will check then images are too big in ff. bdw great for footer..:)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Seems like a different problem from the one you initially pointed out.

Comment: check the site in ff then scroll down and you will see images(lady with pillow)..check that one..size is doubled